# how to call webservices using ajax in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a asp.net mvc 5 and I want to use web api in it and I use a jquery library and below code.but I didnot get proper answer .it returns always fail but I can see the output in the browser.please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>

         function ftoken() {


             $.ajax({

                 url: 'http://charter724.ir/webservice/get_city_a.php?id=367&key=EmlyCD8JOWX22cL8IuNBju5K5',
                // data: {  },
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {
                     alert('success')
                    //   alert(data.data)
                     //if (country_id != "" && zone_code != "" && duration != "" && birthday != "") {
                     //    fPrice(data.token);
                     //}
                     //$.each(data, function (idx, result) {
                     //    alert(result.data);
                     //})
                 },
                 error: function (x, y, z) {
                     alert('fail')
                     //alert(x.responseText);
                     //alert(z);
                 }
             });

         }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" name="name" onclick="ftoken();" value="Click " />
</body>
</html>
```

[I can see the output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2d88.jpg)

Comment: You need to give us some more information. Your AJAX call doesn't look wrong and in any case the problem is not with how you use it. You always get to the error callback because the server isn't returning a success HTTP code. 
Without more information on what the actual error is, we can't do anything to help you.

Comment: ^^ As above.  You need to check the values of `y` & `z` in the error handler (status and error message that the server returned).

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to make an AJAX call to this URL because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)(Yes you can copy and paste the URL in the browser and get a response, but you cannot access it from javascript).

Same origin policy states that AJAX calls will only be allowed if they are coming from the same domain, you are doing something like this:

making an AJAX call from `http://localhost...` to `http://charter724...` - **this is not allowed**

If you inspect the browser console you will see an error similar to the one below:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://charter724.ir/webservice/get_city_a.php?id=367&key=EmlyCD8JOWX22cL8IuNBju5K5. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:10585' is therefore not allowed access*

The only way around this is for you to contact the company exposing the `charter724` service and ask them to enable [CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and allow all requests coming from your domain to access their service calls.

Alternatively you can access the service call using `HttpClient` and get the JSON response.If you really wanted to you could even expose your own set of services which talk to the external service and access **your** service calls from java script:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    string url = "http://charter724.ir/webservice/get_city_a.php?id=367&key=EmlyCD8JOWX22cL8IuNBju5K5";
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: The code works.Place a break point on `string responseBody` and you will see that it contains the JSON data that you are looking for.

Comment: It's possible that the service was offline or temporarily unavailable.You could code some sort of re-try logic if the call fails

Comment: how can I use this json in ajax  {"from":"\u0645\u0634\u0647\u062f","from_code":"109","to":"\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646","to_code":"87","result":[{"price":"134,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10001","to":"10000","date_flight":"05\/12","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0633\u0647 \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDIiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDExNjQ2NztzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aTo4NDA3MTt9"},

Comment: Please read my answer again.It's not allowed due to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: you are right.I can see the result in my computer. but I dont know how to show it success function

Comment: The simple answer is you can't.Please read my answer and the linked articles and understand what the Same Origin Policy means and the options you have available